# how to copy file from AWS S3 to Amazon EC2 instance using .net ??

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to copy file from AWS S3 to Amazon EC2 instance using c# windows application.File is successfully uploading to aws s3.Same file should copy to EC2 instance from my application.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If your application resides inside EC2 instance, just use AWS .NET SDK to get an S3 object: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html

If your application is somewhere else, I think the best solution would be to use SharpSSH to transfer that file over SSH/SCP.
http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx